# Getting additional empty line at the end of the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting a additional empty line at the end of the output.

```
n = 3
space_count = n-1
count = 1

while count <= n:
    print(" " * space_count, "#" * count, end = "")
    space_count = space_count - 1
    count += 1
```

Expected Result:

```
   #
  ##
 ###
```

Actual Result:

```
   #  ## ###
```

Comment: If would be more Pythonic to use the `range()` function. In any case, get yourself a god IDE (can't beat [PyCharm community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) and learn how to use the debugger. Then you won't need to wait for us to help you

Comment: There's really no question here. The *statement* "Getting a additional empty line at the end of the output." could mean that you are currently getting an extra empty line in your output and the question could be that you don't want that. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've specifically told Python that each line should end with an empty string (`""`) instead of a new line (`\n`).

Change your print line to:

```
print(" " * space_count, "#" * count, end = "\n")
```

This is actually the default behaviour. So you could also just use:

```
print(" " * space_count, "#" * count)
```